# How do you conditionally colour text in a R markdown (HTML)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have some code that is running checks on a data set. All my checks will either give a 1 or a 0 -- pass or fail respectively. I am them making a data quality report in an HTML R Markdown.

In R Markdown....

I have written a simple function to turn the 1 or 0 into passed or failed.

I have made the example reproducible by defining x as 1.

For the purpose of this question, I had to put the three dashes ``` at the start and end of the Markdown chunk between two slashes or they would not show up on the question....

````
/```/ <-- omit slashes when putting into R
{r setup, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}


check_status <- function (fig1){
      if(is.na(fig1)){" not run"}
      else if(fig1 == 1){" passed "}
      else if(fig1 == 0 ){" failed "}
    }                           


x <- 1

/```/ <-- omit slashes when putting into R
````

```
This check has `r check_status(x)`
```

^^^
this will render as "passed" when knitted, since x = 1

I would like "passed" to turn green, and "failed" to turn red (and then "not run" can be say, black). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HTML tags with `sprintf` to print the word in certain color based on the condition like this:

````
---
output: html_document
---

``` {r}


check_status <- function (fig1){
      if(is.na(fig1)){" not run"}
      else if(fig1 == 1){sprintf("<span style='color:green'>%s</span>", "passed")}
      else if(fig1 == 0 ){sprintf("<span style='color:red'>%s</span>", "failed")}
    }                           

x1 <- 1
x2 <- 0
```

This check has `r check_status(x1)` 

This check has `r check_status(x2)`
````

Output:

[image]